# Doubt in gamma function

Tags: gamma-function

We all know that from *Euler's reflection formula*
$$\Gamma(m) \Gamma(1-m) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(m \pi)}.$$

But while solving problems there are circumstances where one often ends with a quotient of the form 
$$\frac{\Gamma(m)}{\Gamma (1-m)}.$$
What will be the simplification of it? As an example, how can one simplify $\dfrac{\Gamma(1/4)}{\Gamma(3/4)}$?

Comment: Please use Latex when formatting the question

Comment: I don't know how to use it pls explain!!!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, in general there is no nice simplification formula for a quotient between two Gamma functions of the form $\Gamma (m)/\Gamma (1 - m)$. The best one can do is to use *Euler's reflection formula* of
$$\Gamma (m) \Gamma (1 - m) = \frac{\pi}{\sin (m \pi)},$$ and write the quotient $\Gamma (m)/\Gamma (1 - m)$ in terms of a single Gamma function as follows:
$$\frac{\Gamma (m)}{\Gamma (1 - m)} = \frac{\Gamma^2 (m) \sin (m \pi)}{\pi}.$$

In the case of the example you give, we have
$$\frac{\Gamma \left (\frac{1}{4} \right )}{\Gamma \left (\frac{3}{4} \right )} = \frac{\Gamma \left (\frac{1}{4} \right )}{\Gamma \left (1 - \frac{1}{4} \right )} = \frac{1}{\pi} \Gamma^2 \left (\frac{1}{4} \right ) \sin \left (\frac{\pi}{4} \right ) = \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{2}} \Gamma^2 \left (\frac{1}{4} \right ).$$